# Mitel 5224 will not boot Via VPN

Tags: vpn, mitel

We have recently set up a secure ipsec client to gateway connection from greenbow to a Linksys RV082 on a wireless network.  We can ping and access the Mitel 3300 ICP system from the remote computers via the VPN connection. The problem is that we cannot configure the mitel 5224 ip phone correctly so that it boots up. The phone is plugged directly in to the laptop ethernet port.

We are running windows 7

any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the Mitel phones I have used in the past, it get the provisioning information via DHCP and broadcast traffic. Since you are using an IPSec VPN you will not have that broadcast traffic to help provisioning. You may be able to manually enter the provisioning information.

Also, for our outside sales staff we use the Mitel softphone to help with this, which is something you can do if you have the proper licensing.